# Confusion about the interface design of C++11 random distributions

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std, library-design

Let's take `uniform_int_distribution` for example. In my opinion, despite the fact that it stores a default set of distribution parameters, it is practically stateless. As such, wouldn't it be better and more convenient to design it as a function template like

```
template <class Engine, class IntType = int>
IntType uniform_int(Engine& engine, IntType a = 0, IntType b = numeric_limits<IntType>::max());
```

Quite often, I find myself write something like

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_int(a, b);
... = uniform_int(engine);
```

Or to compress it into a single line

```
... = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(a, b)(engine);
```

Either way, this feels contrived and awkward. With a function interface, this can be done naturally as

```
... = std::uniform_int(engine, a, b);
```

You can still store a default set of distribution parameters if you like

```
auto my_uniform_int = std::bind(std::uniform_int<int>, placeholders::_1, a, b);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your complaint. Are you asking how you can package a distribution and an engine together? If yes, then you can use [`boost::variate_generator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/variate_generator.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my opinion, despite the fact that it stores a default set of
>   distribution parameters, it is practically stateless.

No, not necessarily. For example, if the underlying engine generates X random bits at a time, and `uniform_int_distribution` (with the given range) requires only Y random bits (where Y < X), the implementation may choose as an optimization to store the remaining random bits for use later.

Besides, you want to keep a uniform interface with things like `normal_distribution` (where many methods generate 2 random numbers at once, so you'd return one and store the other for the next invocation), and distributions where you'd want to precompute some parameters at construction time.

Comment: This makes sense. So, it's an optimization.